# Iterrows not keeping the fillna

Tags: python, pandas, loops, fillna

I want to fill in some NaN values from a DataFrame with a value which I can calculate from a linear regression equation. Since not all the values from the DataFrame are NaN, I decided to loop over it.
This is the DataFrame:

```
Country Afghanistan Albania Algeria
1985    NaN         NaN     NaN
1990    NaN         0.645   0.577
...     ...         ...     ...
```

And this is the loop to fill in the NaN values accordingly

```
for index, row in df3.iterrows():
    if row.isnull().any():
        row.fillna(value=float(index)*float(coefs[1])+coefs[0])
```

I was wondering why my DataFrame remains the same after executing the loop.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because changes to the rows in `iterrows` do not affect the original data-frame.

Comment: `fillna` has `inplace` set to `False` by default. You will have to set `inplace=True` if you want this to work without assigning the result to the row

Comment: @yatu that won't modify `df3`. The rows are independent `pd.Series` objects. You modify *those* in-place, but that won't affect `df3`

Comment: True @juanpa.arrivillaga. I guess the simpler way to go is by updating directly `df3` based on  `index`, and use `row` for the `if` condition

Comment: @yatu I suspect you don't need to loop at all.

Comment: Yes @juanpa.arrivillaga, this is simply  a comment on why the actual code does not produce the expected output

Comment: What would be the alternative to looping?

Answer (score 0):

Since `float(index)` is the index of your dataframe and you want to subsititute `NaN` values in your entire dataframe, you can do something like:

```
df3 = df3.apply(lambda col: col.fillna(df3.index.to_series()*float(coefs[1])+coefs[0]))
```